# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'row' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I have written a function, which calculates the Levenshtein distance between two given strings. Two files containing a certain number of strings are read, the function is called and the distance between them is calculated. The program is run and all distances are calculated and printed. However, once it reaches the end, an error appears.

This is the piece of code I have written:

```
def MyLevenshtein(String1, String2):
    rows = len(String1) + 1
    columns = len(String2) + 1
    distance = [[0 for x in range(columns)] for x in range(rows)]
    for i in range(1, rows):
        distance[i][0] = i
    for i in range(1, columns):
        distance[0][i] = i
    for column in range(1, columns):
        for row in range(1, rows):
            if String1[row - 1] == String2[column - 1]:
                cost = 0
            else:
                cost = 2
            distance[row][column] = min(distance[row - 1][column] + 1,  # deletion
                                 distance[row][column - 1] + 1,  # insertion
                                 distance[row - 1][column - 1] + cost) #substitution

    Distance = distance[row][column]
    return  Distance
source = open('D:/TestWords.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8")
target = open('D:/RefWords.txt', 'r', encoding="utf-8")
source = source.read().splitlines()
target = target.read().splitlines()
for i in source:
    for j in target:
        print(i, j, MyLevenshtein(i, j))
```

This is the error that appears:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'row' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is. Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message.

Comment: The error appears right at the end of the program when all strings have been compared.

Comment: The end of the program is `print(i, j, MyLevenshtein(i, j))`.  `row` does not appear in that line of code, so that cannot be where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

The `row` variable is initialized by the inner for loop, but is then accessed outside. Quoting the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/dev/reference/compound_stmts.html#for):

> The for-loop makes assignments to the variables(s) in the target list.
>   [...] Names in the target list are not deleted when the loop is
>   finished, but if the sequence is empty, they will not have been
>   assigned to at all by the loop.

While the `row` variable can be used in a block outside the for loop, it can only be used so if the loop had some iterations (see also [here](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/the-scope-of-index-variables-in-pythons-for-loops/))

Comment: There is no "outer" scope; it's just a question of whether an assignment to `row` in the current scope ever occurs.

Comment: Well, I removed my answer because as proven - I was wrong so I don't want it to make mess here :)

Thanks Barak Itkin

Comment: @chepner - That's mostly a semantic difference, and does not change the information presented in this answer. I consider the `for` loop a scope of it's own, but I can also see why you would consider it part of the current scope.

Comment: A scope is a well-defined concept in Python; it doesn't make things clearer to use the word "scope" when you really mean "block".

Comment: Rephrased "scope" to "block"

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, you are defining/creating `row` in a statement which may or may not run (depending on the loop condition) but you are attempting to read its value in *any case*

Comment: How can I change it so that it doesn't change the result?

Comment: Just indent the offending line twice so that it is inside the inner `for` loop.  This will solve your immediate problem - there may be some extra work needed for computing the the final result, though... but this is already beyond your original question